# Get files created by my app in Google Drive

Tags: .net, google-drive-api

I am fetching files from Google Drive using Google Drive SDK from my application. This allows me to fetch all files from the drive but now I want only files that are created by my app. For now I have created a constant string with the Display Name and comparing with the `OwnerNames` property of the `File`. But what if I change my display name tomorrow in my email attached with `Client_Id` and `Client_Secret`.

Can anyone help me to filter this appropriately? Or is there a way to get the display name based on `Client_Id` or `Client_Secret` dynamically?

Comment: Do you have a app-specific mime-type? If so, you can query files with `mimeType != 'application/vnd.yourcompany.type'`.

Comment: Query should be `mimeType = 'application/vnd.yourcompany.type'` obviously, sorry for the typo.

Comment: Which scope are you using? The drive.file scope will return these, but otherwise what burcu said.

Answer (score 0):

Query for `mimeType = 'application/vnd.yourcompany.type'` on files resources. More details about searching/filtering files are available on https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters